# Conditional Counting record in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table such as the following

```
  SP      MA     SL     NG
 jame     j001    1    20200715 |
 jame     j001   -1    20200715 | -> count is 0
 pink     p002    3    20200730 }
 pink     p002   -3    20200730 } => count is 0
 jack     j002   12    20200731 | => count is 1
 jack     j002   -2    20200731 |
 jack     j002   12    20200801 } => count is 1
```

I want to count record and I want a result like:

```
  SP    count
 jame     0
 pink     0
 jack     2
```

I could do with some help, please. Thanks you!

**How the result is to be reached:**

1. If SP, MA ,NG is the same then sum to SL.
2. Sum is 0 then count is 0,SUM is not 0 then count is 1.
3. If NG, SP is not the same then count is 1.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe in detail how the result is to be reached.

Comment: It is entirely unclear how you expect to get `count` values of 0, 0, 2 out of that data. --- Using `COUNT(*)` you'd get 2, 2, 3. --- Using `SUM(SL)` you'd get 0, 0, 12. --- Using `COUNT(DISTINCT MA)` you'd get 1, 1, 1. --- Using `COUNT(DISTINCT SL)` you'd get 2, 2, 2. --- Using `COUNT(DISTINCT NG)` you'd get 1, 1, 2. --- But, no, I can't seem to figure out how to get 0, 0, 2.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. The result seems to require a `GROUP BY`, so you should at the very least have been able to write that part of the SQL query, and shown it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood your requirements

1. If SP, MA, NG is the same then sum to SL.
2. List item Sum is 0 then count is 0 SUM is not 0 then count is 1.
3. If NG, SP is not the same then count is 1.

Try below Query:

```
with cte as (
select sp,ma,ng,sum(sl) from example group by sp,ma,ng having sum(sl)>0
),

cte1 as (
select distinct sp from example
)
select 
t1.sp, 
sum(case when sum>0 then 1 else 0 end) 
from cte1 t1 left join cte t2  on t1.sp=t2.sp 
group by t1.sp
```

[Demo on Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ca2UEDLJ2bpz5ghRx5u1Tb/0)